# Java Cucumber: How to get string parameter values from all the steps in a single scenario

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java, feature-file

I'm looking for a way to get all the parameters that are being passed in each step ***before entering the actual scenario*** for each scenario in my feature file.

**Sample feature file:**

```
Feature: Login action
  Background:
    When "{login url}" is open

  Scenario: Registered user provides valid username and password
    Given user enters username "{username}" and password "test password"
    And user clicks on "btnLogin"
    Then user is logged in
```

**Parameters I want to get:**

{login url}

{username}

password

btnLogin

**What I tried so far:**

I have tried using a common hook that will be automatically used by all of my scenarios:

```
public class ScenarioHook {

    public ScenarioHook() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setupScenario(Scenario scenario) throws InterruptedException {
    //Here I am currently watching the {scenario} object and I can see all the steps
    //but I still dont know where to get the passed parameter values.
    }

    @After
    public void teardownScenario() throws InterruptedException {
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**
The reason why I want to do this is I want to manipulate the strings (if possible). e.g. all data enclosed in "{}" will be transformed to something else before entering the actual scenario.

Comment: Can you please provide some information as to why you want to do so?

Comment: @EugeneS Have updated my question with the basic details of why I want it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `@Transform` annotation to change the value of the parameter to the step definition.

For this you will need to create a class which contains the logic of the string modification and will return the modified value.

```
public class StringTransformer extends Transformer<String>{

    public String transform(String value) {     
        return "transformed "+value;
    }    
}
```

Next you need to include this class in your stepdefinition using the @Transform annotation in front of the method argument.

```
   @When("^Login with (.*?)$")
        public void helloHere(@Transform(StringTransformer.class) String userName)
    {
            System.out.println("TEXT --- " + userName);
    }
```

This should give you the new transformed string. You can use this to create objects from your initial string. (Actually that is what it is used for)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this immediately. I'll accept your answer if I find it working but would really appreciate if you can tell whether there's a way to do it without having to prefix each parameter with the @Transform annotation. Thanks again!

Comment: You can try by using the concept of xstreams using the XStreamConverter annotation - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cukes/goJdfuv8VHY. Use this link to check out how to create xstream converters - http://x-stream.github.io/converter-tutorial.html.

Comment: Your solution worked. I'll check XStreamConverter out. Huge help! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber `Sceanario` class will not provide you this information as I don't think all steps are actually being loaded and parsed before starting executing the scenario but parsed one by one during the scenario execution. One option I can think of is to create a background step where you will manually include all parameters involved in the scenario. For example:

```
Feature: Login action

  Background:
    Given these parameters are using within this scenario: "{login url}", "{username}", "password", "btnLogin"

    When "{login url}" is open
```